# How can you retrieve the UserCredential from onAuthStateChanged

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app supports multiple identity providers (google, facebook, email), because of this it has made it easier to trigger login flows by subscribing to callbacks from `onAuthStateChanged`. I'm trying to determine if it's the first time a user has logged in. This data appears to be available via this function `getAdditionalUserInfo(userCredential: UserCredential)`. Otherwise I need to trigger this login flow from several different code paths and it will be asynchronous from the main login flow.

```
export const watchAuthChanges = (onLoginSuccess, onLogoutSuccess, onError) => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const token = await getIdToken(user);
      const refreshToken = async () => {
        return await getIdToken(user, true);
      }

      const additionalInfo = getAdditionalUserInfo(???)
      // I want to pass in the additional user info into onLoginSuccess
      onLoginSuccess(user, token, refreshToken);
    } else {
      onLogoutSuccess();
    }
  }, (error) => {
    onError(error)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `UserCredential` is only available when the user actively signs in. There is no way to get it when the authentication state is restored otherwise.

But you can actually also determine whether this is the first time the user is signed in from looking at the `metadata` of the [`User` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#user_interface). If the `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime` values are the same (or *really* close to each other), it is the first time the user is signed in.